# add an image inside a primeNG's DialogModal?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to display an image inside a primeNG's DialogModal.

How can I do it?

Html part :

```
<p-dialog header="Détails de la page" [(visible)]="displayDialog" 
 [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" width="1000"
(onAfterHide)="onDialogHide()">
   <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" *ngIf="selectedPage" 
     style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;padding:20px">
       <div class="ui-grid-row">
         <div class="ui-grid-col-12" style="text-align:center">
        {{selectedPage.pageId}}
             <img  src={{selectedPage.url}} width="45%" height="85% />
         </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</p-dialog>
```

The result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to forget quotation marks in your html. Also, use object binding `[]` instead of interpolation `{{}}`

Change

`<img  src={{selectedPage.url}} width="45%" height="85% />`

to

`<img [src]="selectedPage.url" width="45%" height="85%" />`

Comment: I had try that before, but It didn't work. It displays  :       8653 <img [src]="selectedPage.url" width="45%" height="85% />.

Comment: I just realized `height` isn't closed either. I updated my answer with `height="85%"`